# Java- Extract part of a string between two special characters

Tags: java, regex, string, special-characters

I have been trying to figure out how to extract a portion of a string between two special characters ' and " I've been looking into regex, but frankly I cannot understand it.
Example in Java code:

```
String str="21*90'89\"";
```

I would like to pull out 89

In general I would just like to know how to extract part of a string between two specific characters please.

Also it would be nice to know how to extract part of the string from the beginning to a specific character like to get 21.

Comment: Just a second.. to pull out 89? You mean 90, right?

Comment: Your example code isn't valid Java. Aren't you missing some quotes?

Comment: Ok, now that I've seen Mark's comment I get it. The quote is part of your string.

Comment: yep and a slash should be  String str="21*90'89\"";

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Try this regular expression:

```
'(.*?)"
```

As a Java string literal you will have to write it as follows:

```
"'(.*?)\""
```

Here is a more complete example demonstrating how to use this regular expression with a `Matcher`:

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("'(.*?)\"");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(str);
if (matcher.find()) {
    System.out.println(matcher.group(1));
}
```

See it working online: [ideone](http://ideone.com/Iyafu)

Comment: doesn't work when ' is repeted, i.e. "21*90'90'89\"", returned "90'9089"

Answer (score 9):

If you'll always have a string like that (with 3 parts) then this is enough:

```
 String str= "21*90'89\"";
 String between = str.split("\"|'")[1];
```

Answer (score 6):

Another option, if you can assure that your strings will always be in the format you provide, you can use a quick-and-dirty substring/indexOf solution:

```
str.substring(str.indexOf("'") + 1, str.indexOf("\""));
```

And to get the second piece of data you asked for:

```
str.substring(0, str.indexOf("*"));
```

Answer (score 6):

```
public static void main(final String[] args) {
    final String str = "21*90'89\"";
    final Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("[\\*'\"]");
    final String[] result = pattern.split(str);
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(result));
}
```

Is what you are looking for... The program described above produces:

```
[21, 90, 89]
```

Comment: This is actually exactly what I needed although my question didnt make it seem so...thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

I'm missing the simplest possible solution here:

```
str.replaceFirst(".*'(.*)\".*", "$1");
```

This solution is by far the shortest, however it has some drawbacks:

- In case the string looks different, you get the whole string back without warning.
- It's not very efficient, as the used regex gets compiled for each use.

I wouldn't use it except as a quick hack or if I could be really sure about the input format.

Answer (score 0):

```
    String str="abc#defg@lmn!tp?pqr*tsd";               
    String special="!?@#$%^&*()/<>{}[]:;'`~";           
    ArrayList<Integer> al=new ArrayList<Integer>();         
    for(int i=0;i<str.length();i++)
    {
        for(int j=0;j<special.length();j++)
            if(str.charAt(i)==special.charAt(j))        
                al.add(i);
    }
    for(int i=0;i<al.size()-1;i++)
    {
        int start=al.get(i);
        int end=al.get(i+1);
        for(int j=start+1;j<end;j++)
            System.out.print(str.charAt(j));
        System.out.print(" ");
    }
```

Answer (score -2):

```
String str= 21*90'89;
String part= str.split("[*|']");
System.out.println(part[0] +""+part[1]);
```

Comment: -1: A) it doesn't compile, B) @Goran Jovic answered essentially the same thing about 11 minutes earlier, C) it prints "2189", which doesn't seem like what the OP is looking for