# What is the regexp for removing characters between two "/" in javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

I have the next string "/1234/somename" and I would like to extract the "somename" out using regexp.

I can use the next code to do the job, but I would like to know how to do the same with RegExp.
`mystring.substring(mystring.lastIndexOf("/") + 1, mystring.length)`

Thanks

Comment: check this link [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4962176/java-extract-part-of-a-string-between-two-special-characters][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4962176/java-extract-part-of-a-string-between-two-special-characters

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In a regexp, it can be done like:

```
var pattern = /\/([^\/]+)$/
"/1234/somename".match(pattern);
// ["/somename", "somename"]
```

The pattern matches all characters following a `/` (except for another `/`) up to the end of the string `$`.

However, I would probably use `.split()` instead:

```
// Split on the / and pop off the last element
// if a / exists in the string...
var s = "/1234/somename"
if (s.indexOf("/") >= 0) {
  var name = s.split("/").pop();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This:

```
mystring.substring(mystring.lastIndexOf("/") + 1, mystring.length)
```

is equivalent to this:

```
mystring.replace(/.*[/]/s, '')
```

(Note that despite the name "replace", that method won't modify `mystring`, but rather, it will return a modified copy of `mystring`.)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
mystring.match( /\/[^\/]+$/ )
```