# Split between two chars in java

Tags: java, split

I want to split a string between two  semicolons (:).
i.e.,

> BOOLEAN: Mr. Coffee -
>   Recall:8a42bb8b36a6b0820136aa5e05dc01b3:1346790794980

I am  trying

```
split("[\\:||\\:]");
```

but its not working

Comment: related http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4962176/java-extract-part-of-a-string-between-two-special-characters

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use split with ":" as the regex.

More precisely:

```
  String splits[] = yourString.split(":");
  //splits will contain: 
  //splits[0] = "BOOLEAN";
  //splits[1] = "Mr. Coffee - Recall";
  //splits[2] = "8a42bb8b36a6b0820136aa5e05dc01b3";
  //splits[3] = "1346790794980";
```

Comment: Is it possible to split the string from the second occurrence of  ":" i.e., get the    -    BOOLEAN: Mr. Coffee - Recall

Answer (score 0):

You can use `split()`, Refer this code,

```
String s ="BOOLEAN: Mr. Coffee - Recall:8a42bb8b36a6b0820136aa5e05dc01b3:1346790794980";

String temp = new String();


    String[] arr = s.split(":");

    for(String x : arr){
      System.out.println(x);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

This:

```
  String m = "BOOLEAN: Mr. Coffee - Recall:8a42bb8b36a6b0820136aa5e05dc01b3:1346790794980";
  for (String x : m.split(":"))
    System.out.println(x);
```

returns

```
BOOLEAN
 Mr. Coffee - Recall
8a42bb8b36a6b0820136aa5e05dc01b3
1346790794980
```

Answer (score 0):

Regex flavoured:

```
    String yourString = "BOOLEAN: Mr. Coffee - Recall:8a42bb8b36a6b0820136aa5e05dc01b3:1346790794980";
    String [] componentStrings = Pattern.compile(":").split(yourString);

    for(int i=0;i<componentStrings.length;i++)
    {
        System.out.println(i + " - " + componentStrings[i]);
    }
```