# Getting a specific word in a string

Tags: java, android, string, char

I am new to java, i have a string

```
"rdl_mod_id:0123456789\n\nrdl_mod_name:Driving Test\n\nrdl_mod_type:PUBL\n\nrdl_mod_mode:Practice\n\nrdl_mod_date:2013-04-23"
```

What I want is to get the `Driving Test` word. The word is dynamically changes so what I want to happen is get the word between the `rdl_mod_name:` and the `\n`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following.. It will work in your case..

```
        String str = "rdl_mod_id:0123456789\n\nrdl_mod_name:Driving Test\n\nrdl_mod_type:PUBL\n\nrdl_mod_mode:Practice\n\nrdl_mod_date:2013-04-23";
        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("rdl_mod_name:(.*?)\n");
        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(str);
        while (matcher.find()) {
            System.out.println(matcher.group(1));
        }
```

Also you can make use of `regex`,`matcher`,`pattern` to get your desired result..

The following links will also give you a fair idea:

[Extract string between two strings in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16597303/extract-string-between-two-strings-in-java)

[Java- Extract part of a string between two special characters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4962176/java-extract-part-of-a-string-between-two-special-characters)

[How to get a string between two characters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12595019/how-to-get-a-string-between-two-characters)

Comment: That regex doesn't seem to work for me. I tried adding .* at the start, but that didn't help either.

Comment: The one provided in the OP's question.

Answer (score 0):

I would look into java regular expressions (regex). The String matches method uses a regex to determine if there's a pattern in a string. For what you are doing, I would probably use 'matches(rdl_mod_.*\n)'. The '.*' is a wildcard for strings, so in this context it means anything between rdl_mod and \n. I'm not sure if the matches method can process forward slashes (they signify special text characters), so you might have to replace them with either a different character or remove them altogether.

Answer (score 0):

```
 Use java's substring() function with java indexof() function.
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code :

```
String s = "rdl_mod_id:0123456789\n\nrdl_mod_name:Driving Test\n\nrdl_mod_type:PUBL\n\nrdl_mod_mode:Practice\n\nrdl_mod_date:2013-04-23";
String sArr[] = s.split("\n\n");
String[] sArr1 = sArr[1].split(":");
System.out.println("sArr1[1] : " + sArr1[1]);
```

The `s.split("\n\n");`will split the string on basis of `\n\n`.
The second split i.e. `sArr[1].split(":");` will split the second element in array sArr on basis of `:` i.e split rdl_mod_name:Driving Test into  rdl_mod_name and Driving Test.
`sArr1[1]` is your desired result.