# Extract part of a string between two special characters in java

Tags: java, regex, string, split

```
String stringToSearch = "About ||PrimarySchool|| %  of children in ||Country|| attend primary school. ||SecondarySchoolFemale|| % of girls and ||SecondarySchoolMale|| % of boys finish secondary school. Literacy is ||LiteracyFemale|| % for females and ||LiteracyMale|| % for males.";
```

I want extra string between two special characters like `||anystring||`, but it is not working. I tried to use Pattern-Matcher of Java but it is not working - it returns an empty array.

I have tried to follow [Java- Extract part of a string between two special characters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4962176/java-extract-part-of-a-string-between-two-special-characters?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa).

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("||(.*?)||");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need escape `|`

```
String stringToSearch = "About ||PrimarySchool|| %  of children in ||Country|| attend primary school. ||SecondarySchoolFemale|| % of girls and ||SecondarySchoolMale|| % of boys finish secondary school. Literacy is ||LiteracyFemale|| % for females and ||LiteracyMale|| % for males.";
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\|\\|([^|]*)\\|\\|");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(stringToSearch);
while (matcher.find()) {
    System.out.println(matcher.group(1));
}
```

Result:

```
PrimarySchool
Country
SecondarySchoolFemale
SecondarySchoolMale
LiteracyFemale
LiteracyMale
```

Answer (score 1):

It happens because `|` character has a special meaning in Regex so you have to escape it using `\` character. See the demo at [Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/3nHo31/1).

Moreover, in Java, you have to escape this character with double backslash `\\`.

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\|\\|(.*?)\\|\\|");
```